# Connect between two AWS EC2 Instances to share data from one EC2 instance to other EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I have a specific functional requirement where need to accumulate all waiting messages from SQS to my apache camel component and write the business logic among them.

I am using two ec2 instances with single load balancer.

Suppose if I send 100 messages to the queue. Out of 100, x messages are going to instanceA and (100-x) messages are going to instanceB. Hence I am not able to accumulate all 100 messages at single instance.

> Is there any way, I can send the SQS messages to a particular EC2
>   instance only
>
> OR
>
> I can send the messages from one EC2 to other EC2 instance. Note: Both
>   EC2 instances are running on same port.

Comment: Both instances are puling for the messages? If only once instance is supposed to read them, why is second one also pulling them?

Comment: Another instance is pulling other messages among 100 message.

Comment: It's not a vary good design to begin with. Can you put a lambda which would segregate the queue? All messages would go to lambda, and lambda would send messages to a new queue only for instance 1, and other massages to a new queue for second instance only.

Comment: Ok. So do you mean we can assign instance 1 with one queue?

Comment: If its possible this could be worth considering. In this scenario the original SQS queue is "split" into two new SQS queues by lambda. The lambda will forward the messages to either the first or second new queue. This way each instance gets its own queue with only messages which it should process.

Comment: So how can we assign queues with instances? Because both instances are running in same port number. Just FYI, the services are not microservices here, whole .jar file has been deployed  into two EC2 instances through Beanstalk.

Comment: So the instances are in a single Autoscaling group?

Comment: Yes @Marcin which has min 2 and max 2 ec2 instances. So always minimum there will be 2 instances running.

Comment: These two instances should be same. How exactly do you want to handle situation if one of them goes down, and ASG spins up new one? Or when you have an immutable update and you have 4 instance running for a bit? 4 instance will process which messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SNS-SQS fanout scheme to deliver messages to multiple queues from one source. This way each instance can pull messages from its own separate queue.

I'm not sure about whole architecture, but that's beside the point.

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/send-fanout-event-notifications/

Comment: I just checked the fanout scenario. As there are two EC2 instances running, how can we attach one SQS queue with a single EC2 instance so all messages from that SQS queue to single EC2 instance only, please provide some detail.

Comment: @Arindam I don't understand your question

Comment: I mean as the application is running in two EC2 instances with same port and both consumers which are running in both instances are consuming from single queue. Here do we have a way to attach one queue with one instance only. So other instance consumer cannot consume from that queue at same time.

Comment: @Arindam that is why I have questions about whole architecture. You need to be able to customize parameters like SQS URL on an application basis, you cannot launch identical copies of the same app with same settings and expect them to do different tasks.

Comment: In my view we can run similar application in multiple EC2 instances. Now as per the design we are facing this issue. Now trying to get some way out how we can fix it. If we make one single service as microservice and run in a separate single EC2 instance, it will work perfectly. But we are trying to get some ideas if we can make it work without creating a separate EC2 instance.